# Spockでi18nを行う方法

Tags: haskell, i18n

Webフレームワーク [Spock](https://www.spock.li/) で i18n (多言語対応)を行う良い方法はありますか？
同じくWebフレームワークの [Yesod](https://www.yesodweb.com/) では公式に i18n の方法が[提供されている](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization)ようですが、Spock ではそのようなものは見つけられませんでした。
公式にサポートされているものでなくても、Spock と組み合わせて i18n を実現できるようなライブラリ等があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どの程度便利かまだ分かりませんが、私が作っている（ウェブアプリじゃない）アプリケーションでは https://github.com/filib/i18n を使う予定です。
機能的には単純なので、Spockと組み合わせるのは難しくないと思います。